# How to measure change in altitude at high frequency with Apple Watch

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-watch, watchos, altitude

I am trying to measure changes in altitude with an Apple Watch in a sport activity (Kite Surfing). Currently my App is just collecting data for analysis. I am recording barometric and GPS altitude for comparison at a frequency of 10 measurements per second. Basically, it works and data is recorded, but it seems these data are just worthless. In both measurements there are sudden jumps in the dataset of up to +-10m and spikes in GPS readings of up to 75m. Does anyone have an idea how to get somehow accurate readings? I basically do not care about absolute altitude; I am just interested in the change of altitude.

Answer (score 0):

Use `startRelativeAltitudeUpdates(to:withHandler:)` and when your done remember to `stopRelativeAltitudeUpdates()`

Here is a [link to doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmaltimeter).

Also you can ignore anomalies. for example: if the max possible change in altitude in 100 milliseconds is 2 meters (72 km/h). Then if you see any changes more than 2 meters in 100 millisecond just ignore the data and wait for the next reading.
remember when you ignore one reading to account for the time difference.

Comment: thx for the input. Unfortunately this is not solving my issue, as RelativeAltitudeUpdates are provided only every view seconds without any possibility to change the update interval. At least as far as I could find out. And unfortunately I need at least an update every 1/10 sec. If I missed anything here pls let me know..